# Can't change font

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, fonts

I have the following xaml which includes the font family serif
It shows as sans serif

```
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" FontFamily="serif" Style="{StaticResource largeLabel}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

In fact whatever I put on it doesn't seem to have any effect I have tried custom fonts, font names like arial, font families like serif and it never changes.
I have tried in android and uwp on pc

Thanks for your help

Comment: "serif" is not a valid font family.  Each platform has a different set of fonts you can pick from - they are not universal across platforms.  I suggest you take the time to read the docs before doing anything further.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted each attributte one by one until only the next was left and it started working:

```
<Label Text="Test" FontFamily="serif" />
```

The I re-added each attributte one by one and it still worked, I changed a few other things and it still worked.
I have no idea what was the problem

Comment: You can mark it then this question will be closed.This may be an another problem,you can create an new question with detail info in stackoverflow. : )

Answer (score 1):

> In fact whatever I put on it doesn't seem to have any effect I have tried custom fonts, font names like arial, font families like serif and it never changes.

Like Jason said.Using a font other than the built-in typefaces requires some platform-specific coding.

```
<Label Text="Hello Forms with XAML">
    <Label.FontFamily>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String">
                <On Platform="iOS" Value="Lobster-Regular" />
                <On Platform="Android" Value="Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster-Regular" />
                <On Platform="UWP" Value="Assets/Fonts/Lobster-Regular.ttf#Lobster" />
        </OnPlatform>
    </Label.FontFamily>
</Label>
```

**iOS**

- Add the font file with *Build Action: BundleResource*,
- Update the *Info.plist* file (*Fonts provided by application*, or
  UIAppFonts, key), then
- Refer to it by name wherever you define a font in Xamarin.Forms!

**Android**

- Add the font file to the *Assets* folder in the application
  project and set *Build Action: AndroidAsset*.
- Use the full path and *Font Name* separated by a hash (#) as the
  font name in Xamarin.Forms

**UWP**

- Add the font file to the */Assets/Fonts/* folder in the
  application project and set the *Build Action:Content*.
- Use the full path and font filename, followed by a hash (#) and
  the Font Name

Here is the official document.[Use a custom font](http://Then%20use%20the%20full%20path%20and%20font%20filename,%20followed%20by%20a%20hash%20(#)%20and%20the%20Font%20Name)